# Video doesn't start playing until fully downloaded when Flash is used

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using mediaelement.js I've used the installation Option A: "Single h.264 file".

When the Flash player is used, I notice that the video doesn't play until it's fully downloaded. It doesn't even show the loading animation... When played using the html5 video solution they play straight away, just not on the flash fallback.

How can I have the video start playing in Flash while it's downloading?

http://stage.truedesign.electra-2.titaninternet.co.uk/hunton/1005.php#video

Comment: See the answer on this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058917/mediaelement-js-flash-video-wont-play-until-fully-loaded