# Video wont play until fully loaded

Tags: php, mediaelement.js

The problem is that when video's get bigger than a minute or two I have to buffer the entire video before I can actually play it. When playing very small video's this isn't the case, and I can skip ahead within the buffered part.

I'm playing the video's inside chrome, and the video's are of .mp4 type.

How would I fix this?

**Edit:**

It turns out that a subset of H.264 files have the index at the end, which means that you cannot skip ahead until the full file is downloaded. I would have to swap the index according to:

[MediaElement.js - Flash Video Wont Play Until Fully Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058917/mediaelement-js-flash-video-wont-play-until-fully-loaded)

However, I'm allowing my users to upload movies themselves so I cannot ask them to use this program. How would I convert it myself using php code?

**Edit 2:**

I found a library that enables me to change position of the moov atom. For anyone struggling with the same problem use the following library:

http://code.google.com/p/moovrelocator/

**Edit 3:**

I can confirm the library works great. Definitely recommend it.

Comment: Can you tell which media format, which browser(s) and probably even provide a link to an example media file on the web we can try?

Comment: .mp4, chrome, and im sorry I cant put it on the web. It's running on localhost at the moment because its being used within a testing environment.

Comment: The question you linked already provides you with an answer. Just convert the uploaded videos with one of the programs mentioned and you should be good.

Comment: @Carsten I have a site where users can upload there own video's. I think this process can be done automatically with code instead of my users or me having to use the program.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. I don't see where your problem is. Let me try to rephrase it: A user uploads a video. When the upload is completed, you convert the video on the server, using one of the programs from your linked question. Now you have a video file with the index at the beginning, without any manual intervention from you or the user.

Comment: @Carsten (Sorry to sound like a beginner) You mean its possible to program it so to run that program on my server once the movie is uploaded? I always thought you had to use library's/API's to achieve such things..

Comment: Well yes. To invoke external programs from PHP, you can use the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Carsten said you can use the exec() function. However, I used the [moovrelocator library](http://code.google.com/p/moovrelocator/).

Answer (score 0):

I used http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/ to recode an mp4 video for flash and ie and it worked perfectly.  It starts playing as soon as you hit the play button.