# method of detecting when an H.264 file has the index at the end of the file?

Tags: video, h.264

There is a common issue with H.264 files having a particular index (called the 'moov atom')  located at the end of of the file, meaning that the whole file has to be downloaded before playback can start (as documented [here](http://blog.neilnand.co.uk/2013/02/mediaelementjs-loads-full-video-before.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058917/mediaelement-js-flash-video-wont-play-until-fully-loaded))

Is there some tool for inspecting these files to see if the moov atom is at the end?

I frequently deal with hundreds of MP4 files encoded by different companies, simply using QT Index Swapper on them all isn't feasible. And sometimes the issues caused by the index being at the end only occur sporadically - in one instance only from the client's web server and only in IE9....

Answer (score 1):

- moov atom in the end of the file is not exactly "wrong" place, there are objective reasons why it might be placed there; this location is valid and legal
- inspecting the files is straightforward: you parse the file out and detect atom order and specifically location of the moov atom; [qt-faststart](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/qt-faststart_8c_source.html) is showing how to do this exactly

Comment: > "moov atom in the end of the file is not exactly "wrong" place"  
thanks, I have edited my original question to make it clearer.  

> "inspecting the files is straightforward"  
I was actually after some sort of tool - or possibly a command line utility - that would do this. I'm afraid my programming skills don't stretch to making something myself from qt-faststart.c...! Again, I have edited my original question to clarify this