# Issue in displaying Large Video Files in MedisElement using ASP.NET JQuery

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg, streaming, mediaelement, buffering

There are some **large .Mp4 files** encoded with ***FFmpeg*** in another
project .

I use MediaElement.js to display the video for user (look after the video name in another server, copy it into a Webserver location , and play it) . 
for larger video files, they Cant be played . Does it mean MediaElement load whole Video file , and then play them? 
What should I do for buffering separate section , to avoid this issue?

This is the code I use :

```
   if ($('#player1')) {
        player = new MediaElementPlayer("#player1",
              {
                //...
                alwaysShowControls: true,
                success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
                       mediaElement.play();
                                                           }
              });
        }
```

> I found this link [MediaElement.js - Flash Video Wont Play Until Fully Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058917/mediaelement-js-flash-video-wont-play-until-fully-loaded) , I 'm not sure if its useful for me or not?

Please let me know if any solution comes into your mind, Thanks .

Comment: How large are the files that cannot play?

Comment: @gerdi they're at least 400MB

Answer (score 0):

Refering to this link , https://superuser.com/questions/606653/ffmpeg-converting-media-type-aswell-as-relocating-moov-atom ,  I created a batch file which reads all video files and copy them *with new name* using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -map 0 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

It will copy the file with moving flag to start point with `-movflags +faststart`

Also I needed to add Mp4 MIME Type in IIS.